# what is the difference between internal and private

Tags: oop, f#, private, internal

In F# what is the difference between an internal method and a private method.

I have a feeling that they are implemented the same, but mean something different.

Comment: I think it should be no different from C# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813485/internal-vs-private-access-modifiers

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An `internal` method can be accessed from any type (or function) in the same .NET assembly.
A `private` method can be accessed only from the type where it was declared.

Here is a simple snippet that shows the difference:

```
type A() = 
  member internal x.Foo = 1

type B() = 
  member private x.Foo = 1

let a = A()
let b = B()
a.Foo // Works fine (we're in the same project)
b.Foo // Error FS0491: 'Foo' is not defined
```

Answer (score 3):

internal is the same as public, except that it is only visible inside the assembly it is delcared in. Private is only visible inside the declaring type.

Answer (score 0):

***internal*** instances can be accessed throughout the same assembly, while ***private*** instances can be accessed "ONLY" in the defining class.