# How to access the internal variable outside the class?

Tags: c#

Can I access the internal variables outside the class?

If I have an `internal` variable like this:

```
Class Example    
{
    internal string CommonHome = "C:/myfile/";
}
```

How to access this `CommonHome` from outside the class or another class?

There is any possible way for accessing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Internal vs. Private Access Modifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813485/internal-vs-private-access-modifiers)

Comment: Why are you marking it internal if you want to expose it outside

Answer (score 3):

internal variable are accessible in current dll only.

You can have look at msdn for this => [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx)

Here is some code snippets from there.

```
public class BaseClass 
{
   internal static int intM = 0;
}

public class TestAccess 
{
   static void Main() 
   {
      BaseClass myBase = new BaseClass();   // Ok.
      BaseClass.intM = 444;    // CS0117
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the `internal` members within the assembly you declared them in other classes. Since your inter data member is instance member you need to create instance of Example in a class you want `CommonHome`

```
Example  ex = new Example();
string s = ex.CommonHome;
```

You probably need to give type of `CommonHome` which is **string** I guess

```
Class Example  
{    
    internal string CommonHome = "C:/myfile/";    
}
```

You better use property for CommonHome instead of public data member as you may need to apply some business rule later to this. This is a very good post about the properties, [Why Properties Matte](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter8/propertiesmatter.aspx)r.

```
Class Example  
{    
    internal string CommonHome { get; set; }
    internal Example()
    {
       CommonHome = "C:/myfile/"; 
    }
}
```

> The internal keyword is an access modifier for types and type members.
>   Internal types or members are accessible only within files in the same
>   assembly, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx).

You can read more about access modifiers [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx).