# My project cannot find the constructor, even though I see it clearly defined?

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

For whatever reason, the last line in the code below complains about not finding a constructor for InputDialog that contains 2 arguments.

```
using MahApps.Metro.Controls;
using MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;

namespace order
{
    public static class DialogManager
    {
        public static Task<string> ShowInputAsync(this MetroWindow window, string title, string message, MetroDialogSettings settings = null)
        {
            window.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess();
            return HandleOverlayOnShow(settings, window).ContinueWith(z =>
            {
                return (Task<string>)window.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Func<Task<string>>(() =>
                {
                    if (settings == null)
                        settings = window.MetroDialogOptions;

                    //create the dialog control
                    InputDialog dialog = new InputDialog(window, settings); // error: does not contain a constructor With 2 arguments
```

I checked the code for InputDialog and found this:

```
namespace MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs
{
    public partial class InputDialog : BaseMetroDialog
    {
        internal InputDialog(MetroWindow parentWindow)
            : this(parentWindow, null)
        {
        }
        internal InputDialog(MetroWindow parentWindow, MetroDialogSettings settings)
            : base(parentWindow, settings)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

Clearly the class has the right name, and the correct constructor with 2 arguments and the correct types. So what gives the error?

I essentially is trying to retrofit the code found [here](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Controls/Dialogs/DialogManager.cs) to have a authentication dialog that ask for a 4-6 digit pin With a password Box. Since I shouldn't change MaHapps Metro code, I copied and attempting to modify the code to fit my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The access modifier of the constructor for the class `InputDialog` must be `public`, not `internal`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx

[Practical uses for the "internal" keyword in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165719/practical-usings-of-internal-keyword-in-c-sharp)

The modifier `internal` means that it is accessible only within files in the same assembly

The modifier `public` means that it can be accessed by any other class that can reference `InputDialog`

Comment: Oops, I didn't see that internal modifier. So I am SOL!

Comment: That's not what `internal` means.