# The internal keyword in c# is a OOP concept?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I am a little confuse with the useful use of internal keyword in classes and properties in C#. Using the internal keyword doesn't we mixing logic with physical concepts? It is not bad idea mixing this two concepts?

For example, if we change the physical location for a specific class it can lead to errors even if we not change anything in the code.

And internal keyword is a OO concept or is just some concept invented for the C# language?

Comment: The physical location has nothing to do with types visibility. In the case of `internal`, the only thing that matters is whether the type is part of the assembly or not (and in the case of `MSBuild` that will be the project).

Comment: Hiding internal data structures = data abstraction: the first fundamental concept of object-oriented programming.

Comment: Related [Practical uses for the "internal" keyword in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165719/practical-uses-for-the-internal-keyword-in-c-sharp)

Comment: It is object-oriented—not with respect to a single project but for multiple projects.

Comment: You shouldn't typically be "moving" classes from one assembly to another. If you're doing that a lot you probably need to rethink your planning process. The `internal` keyword isn't the problem.